# Strange blurred screen on my windows phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a worry my long problem, that's my windows phone 7 emulator always shows a blurred screen, but for the device, everything is ok, please see the screenshot below first:

: http://t2.qpic.cn/mblogpic/8aec5160f01ab966dc68/460.jpg

This project was created by VS installed template, and I didn't change any codes. After investigation, I later came to realize that if I use other background color instead of Transparent in .xaml file, the problem will gone, it's so strange.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
```

For this problem I re-installed windows phone 7 sdk twice, but the problem is still there. Any idea from you? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried setting the emulator zoom level to 100%? The blurriness might just come from the scaling.

Comment: I tried, the problem is there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. If you didn't change any code, why SplashScreenImage is visible behind the main page? Are you sure you're using Microsoft's template not a third party template?

Q2. If you'll launch e.g. internet explorer on the emulator, will it blur like your app?

I saw similar blurriness while animating opacity property with visual state manager. Do you use 3-rd party libraries for page transition, such as silverlight toolkit with its TransitionService?

Also, the issue might be caused by your video drivers. You're running on the physical machine, no virtualization? (running a simulator on virtual machine is not supported). Ensure your PC meets [the requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). Please ensure you have the latest GPU drivers.

Comment: thank you, I also feel that something wrong to my PC's GPU drivers.